# How to execute batch file using powershell on remote machine?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to run a batch file on a remote computer but nothing happens on the remote computer. So, for example, I wish to open notepad on the remote computer...

Here's the source I'm running:

```
invoke-command -ComputerName im246 -Credential seth -ScriptBlock {Start-Process "\\im246\temp\x.bat"}
```

...but nothing is executed on the destination remote machine. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: The hostname you're trying to reach is named `im246` and you want to `Start-Process` a batch file located in `\\im246\temp\x.bat`?  Are you sure that path exists on that host?  Make sure your syntax is correct, by checking [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849848.aspx) and reading up on `Start-Process`.

Comment: it does not solve your issue, but here are possible alternatives if you are unable to get `Invoke-Command` working: https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/4l5kkm/what_are_all_or_at_least_the_most_common_ways_to/